# Is there a way to handle key pressing in the fragment?

Tags: android

I have the fragment with `GridView` and `TextView` where I want to handle search button pressing. How can I do this? If I bind `onKeyListener` to fragment's layout it never called.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to handle it on the Activity side and then delegate to the fragment. You need to override `onSearchRequested` ([check the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSearchRequested%28%29)) and invoke a method on the fragment to tell it that the search was requested. After that the fragment can update itself accordingly.